# Set Up Gwebmail

Tags: php, zend-optimizer

i want to setup gwebmail.net.
It uses zendoptimizer.

I am using Ubuntu 10.04 server with PHP5 apache2 and also installed zend optimizer sucessfully.
The zend optimizer is not working to decode it.

the software is available in www.gwebmail.net

Comment: What is your question? What happens or doesn't happen?

Answer (score 0):

this is what your phpinfo() should display:

This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine:
Zend Engine v2.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
       with Zend Extension Manager v1.2.0, Copyright (c) 2003-2007, by Zend Technologies 
       with Zend Optimizer v3.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2007, by Zend Technologies

Answer (score 0):

Hi I got the solution, As i was using PHP 5.3 which is not supported by Zend Optimizer it was not working.
I have to downgrade it to PHP 5.2 to make it work.

Comment: Technical Correction: It works with PHP 5.3.9, you will need the NTS build of PHP though.